# Rails 3.1 assets has no fingerprint in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Just started to adapted to rails 3.1, I started to write coffeescript and sass and everything works fine in development. When I run the server in production, I only get:

```
  <link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the source code of the page, there's no hashcode generated and both assets has routing errors:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"
```

What's the cause of this? Did I forget to do something?

settings in environments/production.rb :

```
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true



    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Thank you very much.

**Add more information:**

in layouts/application.html.erb, I am using the following to include the assets:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

And I've tried `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`  which runs without output anything and then run `rails s -e production` , the problem persists.

And I also tried to set `config.assets.compile = true` and then run `rails s -e production` , the problem still persists.

Please help.

**More information.**
I've seen that the compiled js and css are generated in public/assets folder, but in production enviroment, the files are included without the hash code.

Help.

**Solution:**
Just checked again my project, and found that the root cause is when I was editing application.rb for the support of mongodb. I accidentally commented

```
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

uncomment it then everything is fine.

Leave this for others to remind my rookie mistake.

Thank you very much Richard. Your answer is not final anwser but it helps a lot, really deserves an up vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have the pipeline turned on in application.rb:

`config.assets.enabled = true`

Are you using the correct helper methods for writing the tags? The helper methods should not have the /styleheets and /javascript in the path. Like this (inside erb):

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
stylesheet_link_tag "application"
```

You will also need to run the precompile task as part of the deploy processs to create the files, since you've set compile to false.

The [asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) shows how to set this up with capistrano.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I've add the additional information in the main post. Do I have to use capistrano to get this feature? I am just trying to run "rails s -e production" on my local.

Comment: If you are local, then you do have to run it locally. You only need the Capistrano task if that is how you deploy to a production production environment. Upgrade you app to 3.1.1.rc2 and rerun the task. I think there are some fixes in the precompile task that might fix this.