# stylesheet_link_tag does not link to /asset in Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, jammit

I am trying to upgrade from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1. Previously I was using Jammit for assets, after quite a few steps I got to a point where everything looks pretty good except for CSS part. When I use `javascript_include_tag` and `image_tag`, it generates correct link to `/assets` in development , but when I use `stylesheet_link_tag` for css, it keeps generated links to `/stylesheets` instead of `/assets`.

What is the problem here?

There are several questions related to my problem and I have done everything they said correctly, but I still cannot find out the solution for my problem. Related questions are:

- [Why does stylesheet_link_tag not link to /assets in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824734/why-does-stylesheet-link-tag-not-link-to-assets-in-production)
- [Rails 3.1 assets pipeline in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760382/rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-in-production)

## Update

I found the problem myself, a gem I am using overrides the default behavior of Raild asset tag helpers.

Comment: Can you tell which one it was? I have the same problem and I'm trying everything

Comment: Can you add your your update as the answer and mark accept it as the answer? This still shows up as an unanswered question.

Comment: And please add the name of the gem, which overrides the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the culprit turned out to be an old version of the 'mobile-fu' gem.

I was using version 0.2, and upgrading to 1.1 solved the issue for me. Version 0.2 aliased the 'stylesheet_link_tag' method in such a way that interfered with the  Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelpers module. I found the offensive bit of code by grepping through all my Gems for the 'stylesheet_link_tag' to see where it may have been redefined.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across this issue in the future :).