# Different assets path in Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I have 2 almost identical Rails apps. Both use fat_free_crm as engine. Same versions.

But link tag  in one case gives path '/assets/application.css' and '/stylesheets/application.css' in another.

Same for images and javascript.

Why might this happen

Comment: Are they both running in the same mode, ie both "development" or both "production"?

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824734/why-does-stylesheet-link-tag-not-link-to-assets-in-production  Maybe you don't have the asset pipeline enabled in the second app?

Comment: Did you precompile the assets?

Comment: I do precompile assets
Both on same environment

I will check the asset pipeline