# Rails Application Not Loading All javascript files production

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a personal website Hosted in AWS. Using Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 4.1.0beta1. When I run the code locally, it works like a charm. However when I push to AWS, its missing either some JS files or some CSS files. I think it is missing JS files because if I remove the following from application.js

```
//= require_tree .
```

I can reproduce the issue locally.

**Here is my Gem file:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=danielhamiltondotcom_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.1.0.beta1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

**Here is my production.rb file:**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  #config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app','assets','font')
  config.assets.precompile += %w(.svg .eot .woff .ttf)
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 
end
```

**Here is a snippet of the html.erb page.**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
    "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

I can't quite figure out which files are missing. Please let me know if you need more information. I have been looking around all over and haven't been able to resolve this issue.

I have tried this: [Rails 4: assets not loading in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production).

Comment: The AWS server logs are giving this:
I, [2014-02-27T20:17:53.023473 #24335]  INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/animate-3c459ecd2a5931450ebec168d9eef4ba.css
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...e:0 to(#6c9a15)": expected ";", was ");"
  (in /var/app/ondeck/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):14821

Comment: This can only mean there is something messed up with your sass or scss files. Are you sure it's working in dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue:

1) I had an extra ) in my css file. I removed that to address the compile error that AWS was giving.

2) In my Application.js file I manually required all JS files needed instead of just using the tree:

```
//= require jquery
//= require modernizr
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require twitter
//= require jquery.fancybox.pack
//= require jquery.fancybox-thumbs
//= require jquery.fancybox-media
//= require stellar
//= require nicescroll.min
//= require jquery.isotope.min
//= require custom
//= require custom-home
//= require portfolio
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require retina
```

3) I added gem 'sprockets', '2.8' to my GemFile which i had previously omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Also check your prod server and make sure the asset files are there under `public`.

Comment: I have done the precompile prior to the push I have also tried cleaning then precompile prior to a push to prod server.