# How to load assets in production, Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, production

I've tried everything in other questions: 
[Rails 4: assets not loading in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out!

In application.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

In production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Then in the terminal, run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```