# CSS and JS files added to Ruby on Rails project not available on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added `index.css` to `/app/assets/stylesheets` and `index.js` to `/app/assets/javascript`. I have read that I do not need to reference them anywhere else if they are in these folders.

When I run the app with -e development everything works fine, but if I do with -e production, the styles and functions of those files are not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you build the assets? `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't precompile the assets [which is required when running production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production).

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```