# Rails assets not being found in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, asset-pipeline

I'm deploying a rails application with AWS, Capistrano and Nginx. Everything worked fine except the assets.

The application is looking for the correct assets but the file names have the wrong hash.

Example:
The site is looking for this:
http://35.167.19.250/assets/application.self-afbcf52bc2ee07a55f9597f238014e6c33f9199949f2397157e6d2dc72d3dd0e.css?body=1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
But the actual file is that has been precompiled is: 
http://35.167.19.250/assets/application-fc0ac1dbdd04ee2388affcd3154154fb6c6d1b1a33298abb8cf281c15d4d4c56.css

Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're precompiling assets, you need to do it in production mode so that the fingerprints match.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700219/rails-4-assets-not-loading-in-production) for more details, but I think all you need to do is `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile`.

Comment: Hi Brian, Do i run this before I run my capistrano deployment or do I run this on the server after the files have been deployed? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just saw this - I believe you would do it pre-deployment.