# Heroku app stylesheets not fingerprinted

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, pipeline

When deployed to heroku, I have hit the issue where my CSS file is not fingerprinted, and when accessed causes a 404 error. I have tried the following solution ([Rails 3.1 assets has no fingerprint in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648349/rails-3-1-assets-has-no-fingerprint-in-production)), but it did not help (The original post appears to say that the issues would also show up in local production). When running in local production, no errors occur, however, once pushed up to Heroku, the link goes from `application-[MD5_FINGERPRINT].css` to `application.css`. I tried the solution in the linked post, and it did not help.
The error given is `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css"):` (I tried the Rails 3.1 guide, even though I'm on 3.2.8)

Comment: Could you post the configs you have from your application.rb?

Comment: Sure. I have put this on [Github](https://github.com/itguy51/galleryapp/)